# Cannot use Python Requests module if file is named email.py or logging.py?

Tags: python, python-requests

I have a simple test script:

```
import requests
response = requests.get('http://httpbin.org/get')
print response.text
```

It works when the python script is named `test.py` but fails if named `email.py` or `logging.py`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./email.py", line 3, in <module>
    import requests
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 53, in <module>
    from urllib3.contrib import pyopenssl
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 59, in <module>
    from .request import RequestMethods
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .filepost import encode_multipart_formdata
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/filepost.py", line 15, in <module>
    from .fields import RequestField
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/fields.py", line 7, in <module>
    import email.utils
  File "/home/ubuntu/temp/email.py", line 4, in <module>
    response = requests.get('http://httpbin.org/get')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'get'
```

It appears that `requests` imports `urllib3`, which imports `email` built-in module. Why is Python not finding [the built-in `email` module first](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path), instead of looking in the current path for `email.py`?

Is there a way to make this work, or do I just have to always avoid naming my Python scripts any built-in module that may be imported by any dependency?

Comment: See also ["Force import module from Python standard library instead of PYTHONPATH default"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2952045/12892) and ["How to access a standard-library module in Python when there is a local module with the same name?"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1900189/12892).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, as you indicated in a comment, Python checks for a 'built-in' module of that name.  Not all modules in the standard library are 'built-in'.  You can see the list by:

```
print sys.builtin_module_names
```

If it's not found there, the order searched is outlined by Burhan's accepted answer here:

[What is the extent of the import statement in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20919513/what-is-the-extent-of-the-import-statement-in-python)

> Python searches for things it can import in the following order:
>
> - From the directory where the script was executed.
> - From the directories in the PYTHONPATH environment variable (if its set).
> - From the system-wide Python installation's module directory.

In your case, email is not built-in, so the current directory is checked first.

So, yes, don't shadow a python library name.  Technically you could shadow a built-in module's name, but please - please don't.  It makes Python cry.

Comment: Ah, I thought "built-in" was the same as "standard" modules, but it's not. There are actually very few "built-in" modules.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at `sys.path` and you'll see `''` as the first entry:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['',
 '/.../3.3/lib/python33.zip',
 '/.../3.3/lib/python3.3',
 '/.../3.3/lib/python3.3/plat-darwin',
 '/.../3.3/lib/python3.3/lib-dynload',
 '/.../3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages']
```

That `''` is the current directory.

You could modify `sys.path`, but it's a wiser decision, long-term, to just not give python files names that match builtin modules.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a problem with Requests.

The "problem" comes from Python. `email` and `logging` are standard modules, it is not advisable to name your own modules same unless you understand and are willing to resolve conflicts.

Comment: Why not? According to https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path , python first searches for built-in modules before looking in directories for <module>.py

Comment: I understand now. https://docs.python.org/2/py-modindex.html is a list of standard modules, the most of which are not "built-in modules".

Answer (score 0):

The reason Python is looking for the modules in the current directory first is that that's how Python works. If you look at `sys.path` you will see that its first element is almost always `''` which indicates the current directory. This applies to everything but the built-in modules, which are "imported" at interpreter startup. (They are not really imported, just assigned into `sys.modules`.)

In general, you are supposed to not name your own modules the same names as other modules you're using (whether they came with Python or not). I tend to put my initials on scripts I'm working with just to avoid this pitfall.

Of course, you can just manipulate `sys.path` so it doesn't look for modules in the current directory:

```
import sys
if not sys.path[0]:
   del sys.path[0]
import requests
```

Note that you only need to remove the `''` entry *when you import.* You should put it back after you do your imports, in case you need to import modules of the same name from your own script's directory. A context manager is handy for this.

```
import sys
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def no_cwd_imports():
    old_path = sys.path[:]
    if not sys.path[0]:
        del sys.path[0]
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        sys.path[:] = old_path

with no_cwd_imports():
    import requests
```