# jupyter kernel failing with following error: 'module' object has no attribute 'partial'

Tags: python-2.7, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, functools

I am having trouble running a kernel in jupyter notebook

`$ conda info`

     `active environment : None
       user config file : /home/jazzy/.condarc
 populated config files :
          conda version : 4.5.4
    conda-build version : not installed
         python version : 2.7.15.final.0
       base environment : /data/jazzy/miniconda2  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/noarch
          package cache : /data/jazzy/miniconda2/pkgs
                          /home/jazzy/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /data/jazzy/miniconda2/envs
                          /home/jazzy/.conda/envs
               platform : linux-64
             user-agent : conda/4.5.4 requests/2.19.1 CPython/2.7.15 Linux/3.19.0-51-generic ubuntu/14.04 glibc/2.19
                UID:GID : 1010:1010
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False`

I get the following error when I start a kernel or any existing kernel restarts

`[I 14:02:45.495 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (4/5), new random ports
WARNING:root:kernel 8e593d3c-c364-41ba-8b2d-187c165c52ab restarted
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/jazzy/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/data/jazzy/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/data/jazzy/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 15, in <module>
    from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
  File "/data/jazzy/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipykernel/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .connect import *
  File "/data/jazzy/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipykernel/connect.py", line 13, in <module>
    from IPython.core.profiledir import ProfileDir
  File "/data/jazzy/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    from .core.application import Application
  File "/data/jazzy/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/application.py", line 23, in <module>
    from traitlets.config.application import Application, catch_config_error
  File "/data/jazzy/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/traitlets/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .traitlets import *
  File "/data/jazzy/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 43, in <module>
    import contextlib
  File "/data/jazzy/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 4, in <module>
    from functools import wraps
  File "/data/jazzy/Embeddings/synonyms/utils/functools.py", line 5, in <module>
    import matplotlib
  File "/data/jazzy/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 105, in <module>
    import six
  File "/data/jazzy/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six.py", line 662, in <module>
    iterbytes = functools.partial(itertools.imap, ord)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'partial'`

I also tried importing functools, itertools and running it as following in python and the statement got executed properly

`import itertools
functools.partial(itertools.imap, ord)
<functools.partial object at 0x7f94f5b49e10>`

Comment: It looks like your file `/data/jazzy/Embeddings/synonyms/utils/functools.py` is masking the standard library module named `functools`. If that's a module under your control, I'd suggest renaming it.

Comment: @Blckknght Thank you. I feel like downvoting the question myself!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force import module from Python standard library instead of PYTHONPATH default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952045/force-import-module-from-python-standard-library-instead-of-pythonpath-default)