# Python modules with identical names (i.e., reusing standard module names in packages)

Tags: python, module, namespaces, package

Suppose I have a package that contains modules:

```
SWS/
  __init.py__
  foo.py
  bar.py
  time.py
```

and the modules need to refer to functions contained in one another. It seems like I run into problems with my `time.py` module since there is a standard module that goes by the same name.

For instance, in the case that my `foo.py` module requires both my `SWS.time` and the standard python `time`  modules, I run into trouble since the interpreter will look inside the package and find my `time.py` modules before it comes across the standard `time` module.

Is there any way around this? Is this a no-no situation and should modules names not be reused?

Any solutions and opinions on package philosophy would be useful here.

Comment: I think it's pretty obvious that you should not reuse standard python module names. It's just asking for trouble.

Comment: Why is it obvious? </devilsadvocate>

Comment: Look at httplib/httplib2 and urllib/urllib2.  It makes for an uglier world of libraries, but that is preferable to name collisions and indeterminate behavior.

Comment: It might also be worth adding that the python [style guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) recommends using `class_` over `class` (a trailing underscore) when you're trying to avoid name clashes with keywords.  It might be appropriate here, and to use `import time_ as time`.

Comment: Some 14 years ago I made a module called wave. Trying it out after a long time, it did not work anymore. Turned out that in the mean time a standard module by that name has been added. Yes, I know, I must be old... (and I wasn't clearvoyant). Pretty obvious: Don't judge too quickly.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Reusing names of standard functions/classes/modules/packages is never a good idea. Try to avoid it as much as possible. However there are clean workarounds to your situation.

The behaviour you see, importing your `SWS.time` instead of the stdlib `time`, is due to the semantics of `import` in ancient python versions (2.x). To fix it add:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
```

at the very top of the file. This will change the semantics of `import` to that of python3.x, which are much more sensible. In that case the statement:

```
import time
```

Will only refer to a top-level module. So the interpreter will *not* consider your `SWS.time` module when executing that import inside the package, but it will only use the standard library one.

If a module *inside* your package needs to import `SWS.time` you have the choice of:

- Using an *explicit* relative import:

  ```
  from . import time
  ```
- Using an absolute import:

  ```
  import SWS.time as time
  ```

So, your `foo.py` would be something like:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

import time

from . import time as SWS_time
```

Comment: I would argue that it is not a bad idea *when the module name is in the presence of a namespace*, like a package. This is the spirit of PEP328. See my answer below.

Answer (score 13):

It depends on what version of Python you're using. If your targeted Python version is 2.4 or older (in 2015, I sure hope not), then yes it would be bad practice as there is no way (without hacks) to differentiate the two modules.

However, in Python 2.5+, I think that reusing standard lib module names *within a package namespace* is perfectly fine; in fact, that is [the spirit of PEP328](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#rationale-for-absolute-imports).

> As Python's library expands, more and more existing package internal modules suddenly shadow standard library modules by accident. It's a particularly difficult problem inside packages because there's no way to specify which module is meant. To resolve the ambiguity, it is proposed that foo will always be a module or package reachable from sys.path . This is called an absolute import.
>
> The python-dev community chose absolute imports as the default because they're the more common use case and because absolute imports can provide all the functionality of relative (intra-package) imports -- albeit at the cost of difficulty when renaming package pieces higher up in the hierarchy or when moving one package inside another.
>
> Because this represents a change in semantics, absolute imports will be optional in Python 2.5 and 2.6 through the use of `from __future__ import absolute_import`

`SWS.time` is clearly *not* the same thing as `time` and as a reader of the code, I would expect `SWS.time` to not only use `time`, but to extend it in some way.

So, if `SWS.foo` needs to import `SWS.time`, then it should use the absolute path:

```
# in SWS.foo

# I would suggest renaming *within*
# modules that use SWS.time so that
# readers of your code aren't confused
# with which time module you're using
from SWS import time as sws_time
```

Or, it should use an *explicit* relative import as in Bakuriu's answer:

```
# in SWS.foo

from . import time as sws_time
```

In the case that you need to import the standard lib `time` module within the `SWS.time` module, you will first need to import the future feature (only for Python 2.5+; Python 3+ does this by default):

```
# inside of SWS.time
from __future__ import absolute_import

import time

time.sleep(28800)  # time for bed
```

**Note:** `from __future__ import absolute_imports` will only affect import statements *within* the module that the future feature is imported and will *not* affect any other module (as that would be detrimental if another module depends on relative imports).

Comment: Note that your quote from PEP 8 is **obsolete**. The current version of PEP 8 *endorses using relative imports*: quote: * explicit relative imports are an acceptable alternative to absolute imports, especially when dealing with complex package layouts where using absolute imports would be unnecessarily verbose*

Comment: @Bakuriu, well darn. I didn't know that PEPs could change like that. I will update my answer. I will still maintain my argument, however, that having a packaged module whose name is the same as a top-level stdlib module is not only permissible, but encouraged.

Answer (score 6):

As others have said, this is generally a bad idea.

That being said, if you're looking for potential workarounds, or a better understanding of the problem, I suggest you read the following SO questions:

- [Importing from builtin library when module with same name exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031584/python-importing-from-builtin-library-when-module-with-same-name-exists)
- [How to access a standard-library module in Python when there is a local module with the same name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900189/how-to-access-a-standard-library-module-in-python-when-there-is-a-local-module-w)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, really no good way around it. Try not to name your modules like standard packages. If you really want to call your module `time`, i'd recommend using `_time.py` instead. Even if there was a way to do it, it would make your code hard to read and confusing when it came to the 2 time modules.