# How to avoid module name collision inside package context in python (without renaming)?

Tags: python, namespaces, package

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python modules with identical names (i.e., reusing standard module names in packages)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10501473/python-modules-with-identical-names-i-e-reusing-standard-module-names-in-pack)

From a module inside a package, is there a way to ignore package context for a given import? since the package contains another module with same name as the one that's to be imported from the system, not from the package.

Is there a way to solve this without renaming the other module?

Comment: Can you give an example?  If you are using absolute imports the default behavior is for the system package to be tried first.

Comment: @BrenBarn I'm unable to use an absolute import in this case. It's a python VIM plugin, when python is loaded by VIM, I have available a module named simply `vim` that I can import at my scripts and modules. The thing is, I also have a submodule `mypackage.vim` and at module `mypackage.x` I want to `import vim`, but not the one from package, I want the one VIM provides.

Comment: The main script has no problem using my `vim` module, since it uses it as `mypackage.vim.myfuction("hello world")`, it doesn't clash with `vim.vim_function()`. But the problem arises when I need to use `vim.vim_function()` from inside modules at my package.

Comment: just flagged as duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/10501473/1000282.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried...

```
import mypackage.vim as mypvim
import vim
```

You can use the "as" statement to provide another alias for something you import.

Comment: doesn't work. I have given up and changed module's name =/