# Does Python search for a builtin module before searching for a nonbuiltin module?

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Specific example:**

in `/tmp/test`, I create a file `itertools.py` with following content:

```
def f():
    print("it is my own itertools.")
```

I know there is a builtin module named `itertools`

Then I run `python3` from `/tmp/test`,

```
>>> import itertools
>>> itertools.__dict__
{'_tee': <class 'itertools._tee'>, 'groupby': <class 'itertools.groupby'>, ...}
```

So I import the builtin module `itertools` instead of `/tmp/test/itertools.py`.

It seems that Python searches for a builtin module before searching for a nonbuiltin module. 
This is contrary to [Python modules with identical names (i.e., reusing standard module names in packages)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10501473/python-modules-with-identical-names-i-e-reusing-standard-module-names-in-pack). Why?

---

**General rules:**

From Python in a Nutshell

> When a module is loaded,  `__import__` first checks whether the
>   module is built-in. The  tuple  `sys.builtin_module_names`   names 
>   all  built-in  modules,  but  rebinding that tuple does not affect
>   module loading.
>   The search for built-in modules also looks for modules in
>   platform-specific loca‐ tions, such as the Registry in Windows.
>
> If module  M  is not built-in,  `__import__` looks for  M ’s code as a file on the filesystem.
>   `__import__`  looks at the strings, which are the items of list  `sys.path` , in order.

From Learning Python

> In many cases, you can rely on the automatic nature of the module
>   import search path and won’t need to configure this path at all. If
>   you want to be able to import user- defined files across directory
>   boundaries, though, you will need to know how the search path works in
>   order to customize it. Roughly, Python’s module search path is
>   composed of the concatenation of these major components, some of which
>   are preset for you and some of which you can tailor to tell Python
>   where to look:
>
> 1. The home directory of the program
> 2. PYTHONPATH directories (if set)
> 3. Standard library directories
> 4. The contents of any .pth files (if present)
> 5. The site-packages home of third-party extensions

Are the five places in Learning Python stored in `sys.path`?

Are the five places in Learning Python  searched only after failing to find a builtin module in `sys.builtin_module_names`?

Is "3. Standard library directories" not including the builtin modules? Where are the builtin modules stored? What are the relations between "3. Standard library directories" and the builtin modules?

Thanks.

Comment: You can sort most of this out by just printing both of these variables from a program. The reference docs are probably a more up-to-date place for that kind of detail - https://docs.python.org/3/library/index.html

Comment: I know for a fact that the current directory is always searched first (before loading an installed package). That can provoke ugly bugs if you name a file just like a builtin module. However I would refer to the python documentation (yes, it's long) on the [`importlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html) and all of it's references.

Comment: @MSeifert I just added an example, which shows that a builtin module is searched for before a nonbuiltin module. I am puzzled...

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking about installed packages, not builtins.

Comment: @MSeifert are installed packages stored in "3. Standard library directories" , "5. The site-packages home of third-party extensions", or somewhere else?

Comment: Typically in 'site-packages home' but that is configurable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is only a partial answer but it may help clear up some concepts.

- Builtin modules are typically implemented in C (at least for CPython) and compiled. These are listed in `sys.builtin_module_names`. Examples of such modules are `sys`, `itertools` and `_collections` (note the leading underscore).
- Then there are the standard library modules. These are normal Python files and on Windows located in a folder `lib` inside your Python installation. For example `collections` (without underscore) or `copy`...
- Then there are installed extension modules. These can be compiled modules, normal Python files, etc. On Windows these are found in the `site_packages` folder inside the `lib` folder.

If I look at my `sys.path`:

```
['',                                           # current directory
 '...\\Python\\python35.zip',                  # no idea
 '...\\Python\\DLLs',                          # compiled modules (not builtins)
 '...\\Python\\lib',                           # standard library modules
 '...\\Python',                                # Python installation folder
 '...\\Python\\lib\\site-packages',            # installed modules
 ...]
```

It seems like 1, 3 and 5 are included in my `sys.path` so *maybe* 2 and 4 (if set) would be included in there as well. But that could also be something Windows specific.

As for your title question:

> Does Python search for a builtin module before searching for a nonbuiltin module?

Yes! The builtins are searched first, before it progresses to look for a module in the current directory or the standard library (or in the installed modules).

For example if you have a `sys.py` a `copy.py` file in your current working directory and you try:

```
>>> import sys   # a builtin module
>>> sys
<module 'sys' (built-in)>     ... not the one from the current working directory

>>> import copy  # a standard library module
>>> copy.__file__
... current working directory ... not the one from the standard library
```

If you're really interested in the specifics it would probably be a good idea to consult the [`importlib`](https://docs.python.org/library/importlib.html) documentation and the referred PEPs. Personally, I wouldn't go down that path just out of curiosity.

Comment: Thanks. Why is my example contrary to  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10501473/python-modules-with-identical-names-i-e-reusing-standard-module-names-in-pack

Comment: Because you're using python-3.x which uses absolute imports by default?