# Python: Disabling relative import

Tags: python, import

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to access a standard-library module in Python when there is a local module with the same name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900189/how-to-access-a-standard-library-module-in-python-when-there-is-a-local-module-w)

I'm using Python 2.6.

I only use absolute imports in my application. Now I have this:

```
myapp 
  |
   -- myscript 
   -- json
        |
         -- anotherscript.py
```

In myscript, I have:

```
import json
import myapp.json.anotherscript
```

Because of Python relative import mechanism, import json does not import the built-in library as I want, but my custom json package into current namespace.

Is there a way to disable relative imports in Python or at least a hack to avoid it in this case? Otherwise, i'll have to rename my package to something else that does not make so much sense as jsonutils.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid `from . import json`? That syntax was introduced to solve your problem! Anyway, as a rule, never ever name a module like a built-in.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
```

Described in [PEP-328](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/)

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working with Python 2.7

Comment: @sorin How does it fail? It's working fine on 2.7 for me