# "from __future__ import absolute_import" doesn't disable relative import in Jupyter notebook. How to fix it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

From this post:

[Python: Disabling relative import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13233931/python-disabling-relative-import)

it is indicated that relative import can be disabled by:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
```

However this rule seems cannot be extended to Jupyter notebook. Here is a quick experiment, when I create a python file that has identical name with a python package (in this case networkx). It can cause all absolute import of that package to fail. The following is a screenshot that describe this case:

[image]

The installed package 'network' already contains the submodule 'drawing', yet the import failed with the following message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-e38c4f8fc4a0> in <module>
      1 from __future__ import absolute_import
      2 
----> 3 from networkx import drawing

ImportError: cannot import name 'drawing'
```

How to fix it in Jupyter notebook or Jupyter lab? Does this means there is no way I can avoid relative import?

**UPDATE**: thanks a lot for the answers, one of them is to suggest that I have a corrupted PYTHONPATH (or sys.path), this is not the case, I have added the following line to show the inconsistency of PYTHONPATH and resolved module path:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import os
import sys


for p in sys.path:
    print(p)

print("=================")

import networkx
print(os.path.abspath(networkx.__file__))

from networkx import drawing
```

result:

```
> /home/shared/anaconda3/lib/python36.zip
> /home/shared/anaconda3/lib/python3.6
> /home/shared/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload
> /home/peng/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
> /home/shared/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages
> /home/shared/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/extensions
> /home/peng/.ipython
> ================= /home/peng/git/convnet-abstraction/slide/package/networkx.py
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call
> last) <ipython-input-4-d28ac292787c> in <module>
>      12 print(os.path.abspath(networkx.__file__))
>      13 
> ---> 14 from networkx import drawing
> 
> ImportError: cannot import name 'drawing'
```

Here is another screenshot:

[image]

Comment: This isn't what relative imports are. That _is_ an absolute import, but absolute imports are always relative to `sys.path`, and `sys.path` contains `"."`, the current directory

Comment: I know it's kind of abusing the terminology, but in this case networkx is indeed perceived by Jupyter lab as referring to the networkx.py in the relative path. So how should I call this phenomenon?

Comment: Also, assuming that "Python 3" in the corner is accurate, implicit relative imports are already disabled by default, and `from __future__ import absolute_import` doesn't change the import behavior. (`from __future__ import absolute_import` only disables implicit relative imports, which aren't supported at all on Python 3. It does nothing to explicit relative imports or absolute imports you might mistake for relative imports.)

Comment: I suspect you're running into something [like this](https://github.com/asottile/scratch/wiki/PythonPathSadness)

Comment: I think your update is incorrect. The first entry on the path is almost certainly `""`, which `print(p)` will show as a blank line. I reckon you ignored that output when you pasted it here.

Comment: @Eric thanks a lot! you are right, let me try if I can remove that from path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relative imports are not relevant here. What's happening is `sys.path` probably looks something like:

```
[
 '',  # the current directory
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python 3.5\\python35.zip',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python 3.5\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python 3.5\\lib',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python 3.5', 
 #network x is in one of these two
 'C:\\Users\\<you>\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python35\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python 3.5\\lib\\site-packages'
]
```

When you type `import networkx`, it goes through each of these directories in order looking for either `networkx.py`. It find the one in your "Untitled folder" first.

The best way to fix this is to rename your file, or put it in a sub-directory, `mystuff/networkx`

It would be a bad idea, but you could also do `sys.path.remove('')` to remove the first entry.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, apparently it is not the case, already update my question to clarify

Comment: Sorry turns out that you are right, I omitted an empty line. Credit well deserved!