# Prevent Python relative import from current directory

Tags: python, import

I have a module in my `PYTHONPATH` that looks like this:

module.py

```py
from __future__ import absolute_import

import foo

foo.do_something()

print("I am a module!")
```

I later call this script using `python -m module`. The script works most of the time but I found that I'm cd'ed into a directory which has a folder with `foo/__init__.py` inside of it, Python prefers that folder over the other `foo` module in my `PYTHONPATH`. I assume it's because Python is treating the `foo` folder as an implicit, relative import (I'm using Python 2.7).

How do I get Python to not treat the folder in the $PWD as an implicit relative import?

### from `__future__` import absolute_import does not work

`module.py` and every other module I use has `from __future__ import absolute_import` included. So existing questions such as [Python: Disabling relative import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13233931/python-disabling-relative-import) do not solve this issue.

Answer (score 3):

You can remove the current directory from `sys.path`, or put the directory of the `foo` module at the top of `sys.path`

```py
# at the very beginning of module.py
import sys

sys.path = sys.path[1:]
# or
sys.path.insert(0, <directory of foo module>)

# your code ...
from __future__ import absolute_import

import foo

foo.do_something()

print("I am a module!")
```