# ImportError: cannot import name array, when importing urllib2

Tags: python-2.7, importerror

I am getting below error when trying to import the urllib2:

```
>>> import urllib2

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 94, in <module>
import httplib
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/httplib.py", line 69, in <module>
from array import array

ImportError: cannot import name array`
```

Any thoughts on it?

Comment: Could you be shadowing the stdlib's `array.py` with one of your own?  Try `import array` and then `print array.__file__` to rule this out.

Comment: `array.__file__ == 
'/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload/arraymodule.so'`

Comment: Well, if you did that in the same state that you did `import urllib2`, that rules out the single most common source of this kind of `ImportError`.  Hmmm.  I'd still be tempted to edit `httplib.py` and add `import array; print array.__file__; print dir(array)` right before the `from array import array` line, to see what it thinks it has available to import.

Comment: @DSM- Didn't worked..

Comment: What do you mean "didn't work"?  `print` statements aren't there to fix it, they're trying to help us figure out what the problem is.

Comment: @DSM- I treid that too which din't worked! Thanks anyways..@Ramesh's solution worked :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access a standard-library module in Python when there is a local module with the same name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900189/how-to-access-a-standard-library-module-in-python-when-there-is-a-local-module-w)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems you have a python program named "array.py" in you present working directory. If yes rename that python program or move it to some other directory.