# Intellij error while debugging python code

Tags: python, intellij-idea, intellij-14

```
str = "abc"
print len(str)
```

I am trying to execute the above python program in intellij. I am able to "Run" the program , but I get an exception while trying to run it in debug mode. here is the exception. How can I fix this?

```
/Users/sshil/anaconda/bin/python "/Users/sshil/Library/Application Support/IntelliJIdea2017.1/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py" --multiproc --qt-support --client 127.0.0.1 --port 54544 --file 
/Users/sshil/Downloads/Top-master/Top/DSPython/array/LargestSumContiguousIncreasingArray.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/sshil/Library/Application Support/IntelliJIdea2017.1/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 13, in <module>
from _pydevd_bundle.pydevd_constants import IS_JYTH_LESS25, IS_PY3K, IS_PY34_OLDER, get_thread_id, dict_keys, dict_contains, \
File "/Users/sshil/Library/Application Support/IntelliJIdea2017.1/python/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_constants.py", line 143, in <module>
from _pydev_imps._pydev_saved_modules import thread
File "/Users/sshil/Library/Application Support/IntelliJIdea2017.1/python/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_saved_modules.py", line 15, in <module>
import xmlrpclib
File "/Users/sshil/anaconda/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 145, in <module>
import httplib
File "/Users/sshil/anaconda/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 69, in <module>
from array import array
ImportError: cannot import name array
```

Comment: what did you name the python script you are running in debug mode? Is it `array.py`? If so, read this answer: [ImportError: cannot import name array, when importing urllib2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15770142/1248974)

Comment: Hi Nick, Thanks. It helped.