# Import math module if already one

Tags: python, math, import

Is there a way to import math build in module if there is another module with the same name? 
I can't change the name  of this other 'math' module or delete it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900189/how-to-access-a-standard-library-module-in-python-when-there-is-a-local-module-w

Comment: Why is there another math module?  That's just going to cause all sorts of confusion.

Comment: Thanks DhruvPathak, its working ! I just came into this project, and this module was already here, can't change it :')

Answer (score 1):

You can import modules under a different name in Python:

```
import math as my_math
```