# Name collision between modules imported within third party modules

Tags: python, import, name-collision

Suppose mine.py wants to import moduleA and moduleB but moduleA and moduleB each try to import a module called "moduleC". These are two distinct modules that both happen to be named "moduleC". When mine.py is run, depending on sys.path either moduleA or moduleB gets the correct "moduleC", the other gets a surprise, and chaos ensues.

If moduleA and moduleB were written by different authors, neither of which is us, it is preferable to not modify those modules. Is there any solution available to the author of mine.py that does not modify moduleA or moduleB?

The following questions ask how to solve this issue when you are the author of moduleA or moduleB.

[Importing from builtin library when module with same name exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031584/python-importing-from-builtin-library-when-module-with-same-name-exists)

[How to access a standard-library module in Python when there is a local module with the same name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900189/how-to-access-a-standard-library-module-in-python-when-there-is-a-local-module-w)

**My specific case**

I want to run a program called PyMOL under the Python debugger, pdb. PyMOL unfortunately has a "cmd.py" that it imports and that conflicts with the usual cmd which pdb imports.

The relevant parts of the PyMOL install look like this:

```
pymol/
    __init__.py
    cmd.py
```

PyMOL is run by executing `__init__.py`. This file then imports `cmd` as `from pymol import cmd`.

Working from what BrenBarn pointed out, so far I can get `pdb` to successfully import the correct `cmd` by temporarily removing the `pymol` directory from the front of `sys.path`. After that when PyMOL tries to import its `cmd` it crashes. Somehow I need to remove Python's `cmd` from the import module search before `PyMOL` imports but after `pdb` imports.

**Minimal example**

```
$ ls
pymol/
$ ls pymol/
__init__.py  cmd.py
```

**init**.py

```
# insert some code into __init__.py directly

import sys
pymol_path = sys.path[0]
sys.path[0] = ""
import pdb
sys.path[0] = pymol_path

from pymol import cmd

# test a sandwich of calls that require each "cmd" modules
pdb.set_trace()    
cmd.foo()    
pdb.set_trace()
cmd.foo()

print "done!"

# original PyMOL __init__.py code would follow
```

cmd.py

```
def foo():
    print("cmd.foo()")
```

Try it

```
$ PYTHONPATH= python ./pymol/__init__.py
> /Users/khouli/scr/pymol_scr/pymol/__init__.py(11)<module>()
-> cmd.foo()
(Pdb) continue
cmd.foo()
> /Users/khouli/scr/pymol_scr/pymol/__init__.py(13)<module>()
-> cmd.foo()
(Pdb) continue
cmd.foo()
done!
```

**Edit:** The method given above now seems to work but as BrenBarn's answer states, there likely is no solution that leaves all third party code unmodified as the question originally asked for. This is due to quirks in PyMOL.

Comment: Are you saying that moduleA, moduleB and both moduleC are all independently-installed modules (i.e., it's not that either moduleA or moduleB is trying to import a moduleC from within a subpackage of itself, or something)?

Comment: I had in mind that "moduleC" is a subpackage of both moduleA and moduleB. Could you explain why it makes a difference?

Comment: @Praxeolithic: If `moduleC` is a subpackage of both, it will probably work already, since each will import its own one.

Comment: To be specific, moduleA is the python portion of Pymol, moduleB is pdb, and moduleC is cmd. So I shouldn't have said both are a subpackage.

Comment: It depends on how the modules are doing their imports (e.g., with relative or absolute imports).  There is no general solution to the problem, but in Python 2 relative imports should mean that it will work as long as a package doesn't try to import a global module when that same package has a submodule of the same name.  Can you provide a simple toy example of a package structure showing the problem?

Comment: @BrenBarn Details and progress added.

Comment: I think the problem there is not just the package structure but the fact that you are running `__init__.py` as a script; this places its directory at the front of `sys.path`.  Is running `__init__.py` directly really what you're supposed to do?  That is not usually a good practice.

Comment: Ah, so that's why sys.path seemed to be acting strange. Launching this way is indeed what the comments in __init__.py say to do and is what a homebrew installed pymol does. It's weird.

Comment: But if you're running that file directly, how are you invoking pdb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is not just with the imports, but with the fact that you are *running* `__init__.py` as a script.  When you run a script, Python adds the directory containing the script to the front of `sys.path`, and this globally affects all subsequent imports.

There is no way to customize anything if you are directly running a file that you don't want to modify.  You can't do any sneaky `sys.path` manipulations unless you get to run your own code first, to set up the path the way you want it.  If you *import* the file instead of running it, you have the possibility to use your own code to tweak the paths.

I suspect that this problem is to some degree specific to PyMOL, which unfortunately does not seem to be well-designed in this regard.  Looking at the source code [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/pymol/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/pymol/modules/pymol/__init__.py), I see that PyMOL's `__init__.py` includes a lot of custom code that does weird things like `import __main__` and checking whether the version of itself that is running has various attributes.  You could try using the "unsupported/experimental" method described in the comments in that file, which involves importing PyMOL instead of running it.  I don't know anything about PyMOL so I don't know how that would work.

It might be worth contacting the authors of PyMOL to suggest that they fix this.

Comment: Dropping code at the top of `__init__.py` would be fine. That is in fact what I'm trying at the moment. If running code before the rest of `__init__.py` is an option, what would be the appropriate sneaky sys.path manipulation?

Comment: What I now have in the OP seems to get the imports correct but like you explain, it's necessary to get a bit messy and do surgery on __init__.py.

Comment: @Praxeolitic: Yes, apparently so.  Also, I really can't say how/whether that will work in combination with all the other crazy stuff that the real `__init__.py` is doing.